# Set male or female icon based on the user input Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement

I want to show either a male or a female icon based on what the user is, they choose the gender using a radio button while signing in. Now, inside, on the Profile page, I'm showing all information on that user.

I don't know if what I'm doing is even right, so here's the code:

```
InfoDesignUIWidget(
              textInfo:userModelCurrentInfo!.gender!,
                iconData:
                if(userModelCurrentInfo!.gender! == 'Male'){ // line 68
                   Icons.male_rounded;
              }
              else {
                  Icons.female_rounded;
              }
              ),
```

I'm getting these errors:
`Expected an identifier. :68`

`Expected to find ')'. :68`

Comment: and what if you user is neither male or female?

Comment: I only have those 2 options for now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an if statement where an expression is expected.

Use a ternary expression instead:

```dart
iconData: userModelCurrentInfo!.gender == 'Male' 
          ? Icons.male_rounded
          : Icons.female_rounded
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Icon(userGender == 'Male'
                ? Icons.male_rounded
                : userGender == 'Female'
                    ? Icons.female_rounded
                    : Icons.transgender_sharp,
     ),
```